# multiset combinatorics generation

Tags: python, algorithm

I came across the following problem.

Is there a fast python built-in method to do the following:

```
Input: sets {1,2}, {3,4}, {6,7,8}

Output: sets {1,3,6}, {1,3,7}, {1,3,8}, {1,4,6}, {1,4,7}, {1,4,8}, {2,3,6}, {2,3,7}, {2,3,8}, {2,4,6}, {2,4,7}, {2,4,8}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
>>> map(set, itertools.product({1,2}, {3,4}, {6,7,8}))
[set([8, 1, 3]), set([1, 3, 6]), set([1, 3, 7]), set([8, 1, 4]), set([1, 4, 6]), set([1, 4, 7]), set([8, 2, 3]), set([2, 3, 6]), set([2, 3, 7]), set([8, 2, 4]), set([2, 4, 6]), set([2, 4, 7])]
```

Note that sets are unordered. If you need to preserve ordering, work with lists or tuples:

```
>>> map(tuple, itertools.product((1,2), (3,4), (6,7,8)))
[(1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8)]
```

This readily generalized to a variable number of sets or other collections:

```
>>> coll = ((1,2), (3,4), (6,7,8))
>>> map(tuple, itertools.product(*coll))
[(1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. How can we see the implementation of the product function?

Comment: Here (it's written in C): https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b0866382064f/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l1813

Answer (score 1):

```
a = set([1,2])
b = set([3,4])
c = set([6,7,8])

print [set([x, y, z]) for x in a for y in b for z in c]
#[set([8, 1, 3]), set([1, 3, 6]), set([1, 3, 7]), set([8, 1, 4]), set([1, 4, 6]), set([1, 4, 7]), set([8, 2, 3]), set([2, 3, 6]), set([2, 3, 7]), set([8, 2, 4]), set([2, 4, 6]), set([2, 4, 7])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product([1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]))
[(1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8)]
```